# How to mount windows volume without letter in "Linux for Windows"

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, volume, mount

I have the following task:

1. I installed Linux for Windows in Windows 10 Pro computer;
2. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS;
3. I have a separate volume in Windows computer, which doesn't have a drive letter assigned to it;

I need to find a way to mount this Windows volume without letter in WSL Ubuntu.
I know the volume id in case it is required.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thx, Vlad.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my question wasn't completely right, I wrote Linux for Windows but in fact I was talking about "Windows Subsystem for Linux".

The idea is to have 1 disk drive as hardware configured RAID 0 storage which is built with 2x Samsung SSD 1Tb. But for protection of data on RAID 0, I want to use HDD which will sync data with rsync or any cloud service. I selected ownCloud.
Finally, I want to hide the HDD from the system and configure WSL to use it.

Hereby how it works for me:

1) I created a folder here: c:\Users\Public\wsl

2) I mounted the HDD in the folder created above.

3) After the HDD is mounted, I created a subfolder for my favorite Linux distribution: c:\Users\Public\wsl\ubuntu

4) I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in this folder as it described here: [Installing WSL on Windows 10 without MS Store](https://%20https://superuser.com/questions/1271682/)

5) The point above allows to install ownCloud server on hidden HDD. Now, in order to get it running at system boot, one can create scripts as described here: [how to autoload apache2 and mysql in WSL at Windows boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020837/windows-subsystem-for-linux-autoload-apache2-and-mysql)

6) And finally, to get ownCloud Server running at system boot, even before any user login, one needs to do as follows:

*) Open Windows task scheduler;

*) add a task which runs autostart.sh (see how to make this script on a link above) on system boot;

*) use wscript.exe (from windows system32) as the command to run and the vbs script as parameter. Check this [link](http://%20https://superuser.com/questions/1112007/how-to-run-ubuntu-service-on-windows-at-startup) if you need more details;

7) Finally, we need to setup ownCloud client on the computer and connect it with the server by using http://localhost as the server url.

So, as result of this setup, one gets faster disk system based on 2x SSH configured in RAID 0 and to protect data, one uses a local cloud server in virtual machine to get personal content synchronized with standard HDD. 
If the system uses actively SSD, the cloud won't get time for syncing data. But as soon as resources are available, system will sync data in background mode into the HDD, which requires more time to write the same data.

> This setup allows to use SSD system at full speed as it is required by applications and it does not limit dramatically the performance of SSD subsystem while keep syncing data in slow HDD as computer resources are available and SSD resources are available.